# Unigrams & Bigrams

Tags: information-retrieval

Write code to loop through the corpus and create an inverted index containing the unigram and bigram tokens in each document.

```
import os
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import time

corpus_directory = "corpus path"

def create_inverted_index(corpus_directory, encoding='utf-8'):
    inverted_index = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(corpus_directory):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            with open(file_path, 'r', encoding=encoding, errors='ignore') as f:
                document = f.read()
                tokens = tokenize_text(document, lowercase=True)
                bigrams = [" ".join(tokens[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(tokens) - 1)]
                all_tokens = tokens + bigrams
                for token in all_tokens:
                    if token not in inverted_index:
                        inverted_index[token] = []
                    inverted_index[token].append(file_path)
    return inverted_index
```

Created a inverted index containing the unigram and bigram tokens in each document.

I want to answer_user_input_query

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

```
def answer_user_input_query(inverted_index):
    query = input("Enter a phrase query: ")
    start_time = time.time()
    results = answer_phrase_query(query, inverted_index)
    end_time = time.time()

    if results:
        print("Matching documents:")
        for doc_path in results:
            print(f"Document Path: {doc_path}")
    else:
        print("No matching documents found.")

    print(f"Time taken to answer the query: {end_time - start_time} seconds")

inverted_index = create_inverted_index(corpus_directory)
answer_user_input_query(inverted_index)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?